# jQuery Colorbox: Clicked element hides from background

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have a scenario where I don't need  tags outside of divs like:

```
<a href="#box">
<div class="colorboxElements">click here!</div>
</a>
<div id="box">here is the content!</div>
```

So, I had to use href to each div element and then I gave IDs to the elments of the class:

```
$('.colorboxElements').each(function(index) {
$(this).attr("href","#box"+index);
$(this).attr("id","box"+index);
});

$(".colorboxElements").colorbox({rel:'colorboxElements', inline:true, href:$(this).attr('href'), transition:"none", width:"75%", height:"auto"});
```

Now, when I click on any element of class .colorboxElements, it shows on the colorbox but the problem is the clicked element gets hide from the background and also "Prev" and "Next" buttons are not working when I click back on reaching first element, and click next after last element respectively.

http://jsfiddle.net/etRtm/

Comment: Can you provide code or fiddler ?

Comment: here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/etRtm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/LxC6b/)

HTML

```
<div class="colorboxElements"> 
    <a href="#box">click here!</a>
    <div id="box" class="box">here is the content!</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.colorboxElements a').each(function (index) {
    $(this).attr("href", "#box" + index);
    $(this).siblings('.box').attr("id", "box" + index);
});

$(".colorboxElements a").colorbox({
    rel: 'colorboxElements',
    inline: true,
    transition: "none",
    width: "75%",
    height: "auto"
});
```

Comment: thankyou for your reply, but I have to do it without <a>, iow, use href on the DIV instead. <div class="colorboxElements" id="box" href="#box">content!</div>, see it is SAME div which should show up when clicked in the colorbox. I think now you will get the idea, what i am trying to do.